# Unknown column c1 in WHERE clause node.js sql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am getting data like this

```
category :  "c1,c2"
```

I am doing `category.split(',');` to get data like this

```
category:  [ 'c1', 'c2' ]
```

I want to pass into SQL query for IN ( ) operator like this but unable to figure out way.

```
SELECT * FROM employee emp WHERE .........   AND emp.category in ( 'c1','c2' ) ORDER BY..
```

right now if I pass `category.toString()` it goes like this

```
SELECT * FROM employee emp WHERE .........   AND emp.category in ( c1,c2 ) ORDER BY..
```

which gives Error : **'Unknown column 'c1' in 'where clause'',**

Comment: Does your table have a column called `c1` or `c2`? The error suggests not, and hence the error. Also, what RDBMS are you *really* using. SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products.

Comment: I *suspect* the problem is that you are injecting your values (insecurely?) and when you are you aren't wrapping them in single quotes; but without the application code that's impossible to know. If you're using SQL Server, I would suggest you look into table type parameters.

Comment: table does not have column with those name. column name is employee as I have mentioned in query. I am using MySQL

Comment: *"emp.category in ( c1,c2 )"* will, however, be referencing the columns `c1` and `c2` *not* the **literal strings** with those values. *"I am using MySQL"* Then please correct your tags to retag [tag:mysql], as I removed the conflicting tags.

Comment: We have injected values like this in whole project. It works when data is in numbers like id in ( 446766,446805). causing issue with string

Comment: *" It works when data is in numbers"* because numbers don't go in single quotes. Sounds like your application is riddled with severe security flaws (SQL Injection), if I am honest. For example, what do you think would happen if someone passed the value `"emp.category)--"` for `category`? Or, perhaps, in one of your queries with numbers `"1), OR 1 = 1--"`

Comment: what I meant is, we fetching some records and getting their IDs and using them in another query. I know numbers don't require quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the Paramtries query it will solve your problem.

pass ( ? ) like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee emp 
WHERE .........   
  AND emp.category IN ( ? ) 
ORDER BY ..
```

You can pass your value in Parameter Array.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, you need to have your query built as `emp.category in ( 'c1','c2' )`.

Your method currently generates `emp.category in ( c1,c2 )`

So you need a proper escaping of your values so that the ingested values are indeed quoted. It depends on how you build the query exactly, but a proper escaping mechanism should not have this problem.

start by testing with `category :  "'c1','c2'"` just to wrap things in your head.

But you will surely need to dive into how your queries are built. An invalid escaping mechanism can lead to a lot of security issues as it will inevitably lead to SQL injections attacks.

In node.js land, you can use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-format module in order to properly escape hand-built queries. You could also use a highler level query builder like knex.

Comment: I got this solution. I am already thinking about it. But not sure how will I make it like category :  "'c1','c2'"

Comment: You need to explain how you query string is build. Do you use a library (might be a bug) or just concatenate strings (not advised for SQL query building) ?

Comment: I am concatenating a string to make query but open to suggestion